# Can I use the MessageUI framework way of sending mail without popping up the mail modal view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

For my purposes, all of the information that I need in my email, can be added without the mail modal view that lets the user hit the send button. So I'm wondering if there is anyway to leverage the same convenient mail api, but skip the modal view?

Just set all of the email information and send off the email without any user intervention?

Thanks

Comment: I hope not. I don't want apps to be able to send email out of my phone without my knowledge!

Comment: Haha. That is a good point. I assure you that my intentions are to add convenience, not send unauthorized email messages. I guess it's not that big of a deal to have the confirmation modal come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not what MessageUI is for. Otherwise it wouldn't be called Message***UI***!

One alternative is to find a simple SMTP library to send email, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/).